# same-origin request blocked as cross-origin

Tags: google-chrome, cors

I have some error reporting in a website I manage, and every once in a while I get an error report of `Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://domain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame` .  Following the line numbers in the stack trace, I see it is where I access `document.querySelector("iframe#results-map").contentWindow` .  However, this iframe is accessed by a relative URL: `/html/googleresultsmap.html` so it cannot be cross-origin (indeed it works 99.9% of the time as I don't get many reports like this).  All the reports report Chrome (various versions/variants).

So how can a relative URL cause a cross-origin frame?

`<iframe src="/html/googleresultsmap.html" id="results-map"></iframe>`

`document.querySelector("iframe#results-map").contentWindow`

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to be the case when `document.domain` is explicitly set someplace. If you try Safari developer tools, I found it much more helpful in this case, with a message like:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "{accessor}" from accessing a frame with origin "{accessee}". The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to "blah.com", but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.
```

Comment: I'm not setting `document.domain`.  Where could it possibly be set?  Maybe a browser extension?  How would I work around it?

Comment: Have you tried with Safari dev tools, does it provide a more thorough error message?

Comment: I can't reproduce it.  It's not happening on my machine.  It only seems to be on 0.1% of users' machines.